# Convert array of arrays of strings to one object in JS

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say that I have the following array:

```
[
 {
   path: ["info", "address", "city"]
 },
 {
   path: ["info", "first_name"]
 },
 {
   path: ["info", "last_name"]
 },
 {
   path: ["score"]
 }
]
```

And I want to convert this to:

```
{
  personal_info: {
    first_name: some_value,
    last_name: some_value,
    adress: {
     city: some_value
    }
  },
  score: some_value
}
```

Note: some_value is just another key represented before path key.

I have tried something in this structure:

```
for(let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
  if(i == a.length - 1)
    res = { [a[i]] : value};        // assign the value
  else
    res = { [a[i]] : res};          //put the prev object
}
```

However I don't know how to concatenate from multiple arrays to one object.

Comment: Where do the `some_value` values come from?

Comment: You have an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder its just another key located before the `path` key.

Comment: Well, you should post it

Comment: @FrankerZ edited. Thanks.

Comment: @Raz Don't jump the gun and choose an answer yet. There are plenty of other good ones that will likely be posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
 {
   path: ["info", "address", "city"]
 },
 {
   path: ["info", "first_name"]
 },
 {
   path: ["info", "last_name"]
 },
 {
   path: ["score"]
 }
];

const newObject = {};

function setValueByKeypath(currentObject, path, value) {
    for (let i = 0, len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
        const key = path[i];
        // if it is the last path part, add the value else we have to got on building objects
        const keyValue = (i === len - 1) ? value : {};
        // test if there is already a given key and if not create one or if it is the last part of the key add the value
        if (typeof currentObject[key] === "undefined") {
            currentObject[key] = keyValue;
        }
        currentObject = currentObject[key];
    }       
}

for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    // build the nested path in the object by the given array data[i].path
    setValueByKeypath(newObject, data[i].path, "someValue");
}

console.log(newObject);

// create a reference 'personal_info' to 'info'
newObject.personal_info = newObject.info;
// delete the 'info' key
delete newObject.info;

console.log(newObject);
```

First go through those paths. And secondly turn the info key into a personal_info key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the function `reduce` or the function `forEach` to build that desired output.

*This approach uses the function `reduce`, and for the specific values you need to decide how to set them.*

```js
let arr = [ {   path: ["info", "address", "city"] }, {   path: ["info", "first_name"] }, {   path: ["info", "last_name"] }, {   path: ["score"] }],
    value = 'some_value',
    personalInfoKey = 'personal_info',
    result = arr.reduce((a, {path}) => {  
      let [type, ...keys] = path;
      if (type === 'info') {
        if (keys.length === 1) a[personalInfoKey][keys.pop()] = value;
        else {
          a[personalInfoKey] = a[personalInfoKey] || {};
          let current = a[personalInfoKey];
          keys.forEach((k, i, ar) => current = current[k] = i === ar.length - 1 ? value : {});
        }
      } else a[type] = value;

      return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 `reduce`s. The first one is to loop thru the array. The second one is to construct the result object.

```js
var arr = [
  {"path":["info","address","city"],"value":1},
  {"path":["info","first_name"],"value":2},
  {"path":["info","last_name"],"value":3},
  {"path":["score"],"value":4}
]

var result = arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  var t = v.path.reduce((a, o, i) => {
    o = o === "info" ? "personal_info" : o;
    if (i < v.path.length - 1 && !a[o]) a[o] = {};
    if (i < v.path.length - 1) return a[o];
    else return a;
  }, c);
  t[v.path[v.path.length - 1]] = v.value;
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and reduce the keys with default object for assigning the vlaue.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();
    path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
    return object;
}

var data = [{ value: "Düsseldorf", path: ["info", "address", "city"] }, { value: "Jane", path: ["info", "first_name"] }, { value: "Smith", path: ["info", "last_name"] }, { value: 11000, path: ["score"] }],
    object = data.reduce((o, { path, value }) => setValue(o, [...path], value), {});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```